# MS Sync Toolkit how to handle huge initial download

Tags: performance, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

We're using Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit to allow some iOS devices to synchronize their SQLite local storage with a central SQL Server database over an OData service (just like the sample does).

The problem is that the central database is quite big (more than 500 MB) and that the customer want to initially replicate all his content on their devices.

So we configured the service to **sync all tables** but it crashes the first time a device tries to sync (`OutOfMemoryException`).

How should we design/configure the service to manage such a situation? Setting filters doesn't seem to fit our needs since we need all the data.

I should add that we tried to configure `SetDownloadBatchSize` with no luck. Maybe there is something to configure on the client as well?

Comment: it's hard to say how to fix it .. are you get whole response to string and then getting OOM exception? you wrote that you had try SetDownloadBatchSize but with what value

Comment: Hi Selvin, we tried with 2MB but each chunk weights at least 10MB (which we suppose are serialization overhead and unbreakable big objects). We kept this solution as it takes time (around 10 minutes for first sync) but it works.